# Why is my docker container getting a root group when running in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm in the process of ensuring all of our containers are not running as root. I'm having a bit of trouble though with group access. The short version, when I build a container, and run it locally, I get the following:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh f83823c8ee6c
~ $ id
uid=1000(metadata) gid=1000(metadata)
```

However when I run this same container in our kubernetes clusters I get the following:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get pods -l app=metadata | grep -v NAME | awk '{print $1 }' | xargs -I {} kubectl -n kube-system exec  {} -- id 
uid=1000(metadata) gid=1000(metadata) groups=0(root),1000(metadata)
```

The fact that the container is assigned multiple groups when running in the cluster is concerning to me and what I'm trying to solve. I expected the same output when running in the k8s cluster and when running with docker directly.

---

For some extra background on our deployments, and configuration... The Dockerfile this container is built with:

```
# build stage
FROM golang:1.13-alpine AS build-env
RUN apk add --no-cache --update alpine-sdk curl
ENV REPO_PATH=**redacted**
COPY . $REPO_PATH
WORKDIR $REPO_PATH
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
RUN make dep
RUN make build

# final stage
FROM alpine:3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env **redacted**/bin/server /app/
RUN apk add --no-cache --update ca-certificates && \
  addgroup -g 1000 metadata && \
  adduser -D -g "metadata user" -H -h "/app" -G "metadata" -u 1000 metadata && \
  chown -R metadata:metadata /app
USER 1000:1000
ENTRYPOINT /app/server
```

Our kubernetes version is 1.15.6, and I'm aware that RunAsGroup requires a feature gate, our running controller options (we roll our own clusters, do not use one of the cloud providers managed options):

```
kubectl -n kube-system get pods -l=k8s-app=kube-controller-manager | tail -1 | awk ' { print $1 }' | xargs -I {} kubectl -n kube-system get pod {} -o=json | jq '.spec.containers[].command' 
[
  "/hyperkube",
  "kube-controller-manager",
  "--log-dir=/var/log/kube-controller",
  "--logtostderr=false",
  "--cluster-cidr=172.16.0.0/16",
  "--allocate-node-cidrs=false",
  "--authentication-kubeconfig=/srv/kubernetes/controller/kubeconfig",
  "--authorization-kubeconfig=/srv/kubernetes/controller/kubeconfig",
  "--cloud-provider=aws",
  "--feature-gates=CustomResourceSubresources=true",
  "--feature-gates=ExpandInUsePersistentVolumes=true",
  "--feature-gates=ExpandPersistentVolumes=true",
  "--feature-gates=TaintNodesByCondition=true",
  "--feature-gates=TTLAfterFinished=true",
  "--feature-gates=RunAsGroup=true",
  "--kubeconfig=/srv/kubernetes/controller/kubeconfig",
  "--root-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt",
  "--service-account-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/signing.key",
  "--use-service-account-credentials=true"
]
```

The deployment contains the following:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get deployment metadata -o=json | jq .spec.template.spec.securityContext
{
  "fsGroup": 1000,
  "runAsGroup": 1000,
  "runAsNonRoot": true,
  "runAsUser": 1000
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the supplementalGroups under securityContexts section.

```
 securityContext: {
    "supplementalGroups": [1000]
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to include this as an empty list and it didn't do anything, I figured no supplimental groups were needed. Specifying the primary GID ensured the container was running in just the intended group.